# A single word for multiple things that supersede others

Tags: single-word-requests

I am building a system for my company for our product versioning. Assume there are multiple versions and sub-versions of a product:

- V1

  - V1.1
  - V1.2
  - V1.3
- V2

  - V2.1
  - V2.2
  - V2.3

etc.

I need to filter on the latest sub-version of each 'full' version - V1.3 and V2.3 in the above example. It needs to be the same word so that we can get both to show in a filter. We have already agreed that in the above example, all old sub-versions (Versions 1.1-1.2 & 2.1-2.2) will be defined as 'Superseded'.

For the others, we have drafted some basic ideas:

- Latest
- Current
- New

...but none of these really work as they don't apply to V1.3 - this is no longer the 'current' or 'new' version **overall** so would be confusing from a user point of view.

What is the best word to use in this scenario?

Comment: subversion doesn't mean sub-version.

Comment: I actually doubted myself on that before posting but the Google results threw me off! Edited now.

Comment: "definitive" ? Are the older versions still under development, i.e. might there be a V1.4 in the future or will the newer versions only be V[max].N ? If V1.3 is the permanent "last of the V1s" you could maybe say "final" or "terminal" ?

Comment: Saying "highest patch levels of all versions" should get the message across. This works for software.

Comment: But isn't V1.3 superseded by V2.1, so only V2.3 is current?

Comment: I'd suggest "latest versions" (or "latest supported versions") for 1.3+2.3, and "latest version" for 2.3 only. There is complexity because I assume some branches are being updated/supported/available while others are not (e.g. there's probably a 0.8/0.9/etc which you're not offering for download, and in future you may not support 1.x but have 2.x, 3.x, etc).

Answer (score 1):

See the accepted answer to [How to do version numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615227/how-to-do-version-numbers)

You can define the decimal places, such as "[major].[minor].[release].[build]", and then specify the final version of each major release (or whatever terms you wish to use).

Answer (score 1):

Suggest ***revisions***

Anything *after* the original version is a ***revision***, many ***revisions*** may supercede an earlier version.

- A new revision supercedes all prior versions.
- The ***latest*** revision is synonymous with the current version. 
  *(in this context, an original, unaltered document might be Revision* **0*** (zero)
- There can be many ***revisions.***

> ***revision, n.*** 
> b. The result of *revising*; a revised or amended
> version of a text, etc. 
> c. A single amendment or correction to a
> piece of work.
>
> (plural) ***revisions***
>
> - The final ***revisions*** are done and a lot of the original zap is gone
>   from the book, but there are parts of it I think you might like. 
>   ***-- H. S. Thompson Let. 28 June in Proud Highway (1997) 577***
> - With a few small ***revisions***, you should get it published without too much difficulty. 
>   ***-- A. Martin Walking on Water (1992) iii.***
> - The board made only one ***revision*** to the staff plan, reassigning board member Larry Gauvreau's neighborhood. 
>   ***-- Charlotte (N. Carolina) Observer (Nexis) 10 June 1 A***

> [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/164894?rskey=PRkmv1&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

Answer (score 0):

You might use the term "**leaf** versions" to indicate that you have multiple branches and there is one active endpoint on any particular branch. With this mental imagery, you would have to imagine that once a new leaf version is produced, the previous leaf version is no longer a viable leaf. (E.g., v1.3 becomes a new leaf and v1.2 has been dropped.)